# Calculating probabilities of an nth step transition matrix for discrete time markov chains

Tags: conditional-probability, stochastic-processes, markov-process

"Let $\{X_n, n \geq 0\}$ be a DTMC with state space $S = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ and the following transition probability matrix:

$$
P = \begin{pmatrix} 0.1 & 0.0 & 0.2 & 0.3 & 0.4 \\ 0.0 & 0.6 & 0.0 & 0.4 & 0.0 \\ 0.2 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.4 & 0.4 \\ 0.0 & 0.4 & 0.0 & 0.5 & 0.1 \\ 0.6 & 0.0 & 0.3 & 0.1 & 0.0 \end{pmatrix}
$$

with the initial distribution as:

$$
a = \begin{pmatrix} 0.5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.5 \end{pmatrix}.
$$

Compute $P(X_2 = 2, X_4 = 5)$"

Also, how do I do this? I'm not even sure what it means. Is this asking me to work out the probability of $X_4 = 5$ given that I have $X_2 = 2$?

EDIT: The matrix is correct. From the previous part of the question (that I didn't post), $P(X_2 = 2) = 0.08$. In the answers, my lecturer uses the Chapman Kolmogorov equations. Does this make the answer any clearer?

EDIT 2: Edited to bump to the top as I have commented on whuber's post with a couple of questions

Comment: $P(X_2=2,X_4=5)$ is the *joint probability* of $X_4=5$ and $X_2=2$ not the conditional probability. Also, is this homework?

Comment: It's old homework, so I have the answers, but I don't understand why. The answer to that question is 0.0032. How do you calculate joint probability?

Comment: $P(A,B) = P(A)P(B)$

Comment: Using the definition of conditional probability, you'll find that $$P(X_4 = 5, X_2 = 2) = P(X_4 = 5 | X_2 = 2) \cdot P(X_2 = 2)$$ You can get a handle on $P(X_4 = 5 | X_2 = 2)$ using the transition matrix (hint: use $P^2 = P P$) and, since you don't know $X_1$, you have to calculate $P(X_2 = 2)$ using [the law of total probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability).

Comment: It looks to me like $P(X_2=2)=0$ right? You can only get to state 2 from state 2 or 4 and the probability of being in those states on step 1 is both 0. You should make sure you transcribed your matrix correctly,@Kaish, otherwise I dont see how the answer is 0.0032.

Comment: @Jerad It all depends on what state you start from: your comment ignores that.

Comment: I assumed the chain begins in some distinguished start state at $X_0$, whose transition probabilities for $X_1$ were given by $a$.

Comment: Re the edit: $.08 = 2/25$, the probability shown in the third figure of my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a graphical representation of the chain, with the vertices $2$ and $5$ highlighted:

[image: figure 1]

The initial state $a$ can be indicated by labeling the vertices with their values, highlighting the nonzero values:

[image: figure 2]

Two transitions from $a$, as computed by the matrix product $a\mathbb{P}\mathbb{P} = a\mathbb{P}^2$, is this distribution:

[image: figure 3]

The weight on vertex $2$ is precisely the chance of reaching $2$ after two steps; that is, it is $\Pr(X_2=2)$.  To represent this event, we now zero out all other weights, leaving the distribution $b = (0, 2/25, 0, 0, 0)$.  The question asks us to take two more steps, beginning at $b$, computing $b\mathbb{P}\mathbb{P} = b\mathbb{P}^2$:

[image: figure 4]

The labels give the new distribution. All two-step paths from vertex $2$ to vertex $4$ are highlighted.  (There is just one, making it easy to compute the new distribution: $2/25$ is multiplied by $p_{2,4}=2/5$, giving $4/125$ for the transition from $2$ to $4$, then that is multiplied by $p_{4,5}=1/10$, yielding $4/1250=2/625$ for the double transition $2\to 4\to 5$.  In more complicated situations we would have to examine all possible paths from $2$ to $5$ and add their contributions.)

Evidently, the chance of reaching vertex $2$ at step $2$ *and* then arriving at vertex $5$ at step $4$ is the final value at vertex $5$, $2/625 = 0.0032$.

Comment: I'm still coming up with $P(X_2=2)=0$. Consider that $P(X_1) = a = (0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0.5)$. For the second step, we have $P(X_2) = aP$ which is simply the average of row 1 and 5 in $P$, which is $(0.35, 0, 0.25, 0.2, 0.2)$. Why is it that me and mimshot above both get this answer yet you end up with the answer that the OP provided?

Comment: @Jerad you have to interpret $a$ as $X_0$ rather than as $X_1$, that's all.  Did you notice the condition "$n\ge 0$" at the very beginning of the question?

Comment: @whuber I have the right answer now. What I did was I had matrix $P$, squaring it gave me the 2nd step matrix and multiplying it with my initial distribution gave me $P(X_2 = 2)$. Then, I said my new "initial distribution" was $b = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0.08 &0 &0 &0 \end{pmatrix}$ (like you said) and then I multiplied this by $P^2$ and it gave me the right answer as 0.0032. A few questions, why do I multiply b with $P^2$ and not $P^4$? Let's say I had to work out $P(X_2 = 2, X_3 = 3)$, then how would I do the $X_3$ bit, would I multiply b with just P?

Comment: That's right. If you multiply $b$ (the state after two transitions) by $\mathbb{P}^4$, you are making *four* transitions and therefore are computing the distribution reached from $b$ after four transitions: this would be relevant to comparing events at step $2$ and step $6$.

Comment: Ohhh ok, I understand. So if I was working out $P(X_3 = \mathrm{something})$ then I would do $b \cdot P$ right? So in a way this is like the Chapman Kolmogorov equations because I've gone from state 0 to 2 and then 2 to 4 right?

Comment: You've got it.  It looks like you're becoming comfortable moving back and forth between the graphical and algebraic representations of the chain.

Answer (score 0):

It's asking you to work out the probability that $X_2=2$ *and* $X_4 = 5$.

In general if you know the probability distribution of states at time $t$ is $a_t$ then the distribution at time $t+1$ (i.e., $a_{t+1}) is given by:

$$a_{t+1}^T = P * a_t^T$$

Note that having $a$ be a column vector would have been simpler since you wouldn't have needed the transpose, but I'm keeping your notation.

To find $a$ more than one step in advance we keep multiplying by $P$.

$$a_{t+2}^T = P^2 * a_t^T$$
$$a_{t+3}^T = P^3 * a_t^T$$

Since we know:

$$P(X_4 = 5, X_2 = 2) = P(X_4 = 5 | X_2 = 2) \cdot P(X_2 = 2)$$

We could calculate each of those two probabilities with some matrix multiplication. But note that $P(X_2 = 2) = 0$ because $X_1$ can only be 1 or 5 and $P_{1,2}=0$ and $P_{5,2}=0$

Thus the answer is zero.

Comment: This is incorrect because you are following a different convention for subscripting the $X$'s: they start at $0$, not $1$.  Bear in mind, too, that the convention with Markov chains is to *right* multiply by the transition matrix.  You can always tell which convention is in use by checking the sum-to-unity condition. By multiplying on the left by this $P$, whose *rows* sum to unity, you are not computing correctly.